# Deeplinks not working on iOS with ionic app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic3

I need your help because I can't use Deeplinks properly on iOS when I build my ionic app.

Let me explain. We are two people working on the project. My fellow worker implemented the deeplinks with the ionic plugin : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/
He set up the whole thing with files on the server and it is working with his computer. Both on emulator and applications on mobiles, both on Android and iOS.

Now, I tried to configure my computer to also build and release the apps with deeplinks. So I removed the platforms, add the plugin with proper configuration (used the same command as he did), add the platforms again.
Then I configured the applinks with Android Studio, and deeplinks are working on Android. 
I tried to configure xCode with associated domains on the example of applinks:yourdomain.com , then I verified my app was signed with the Team certificate, yes it is.

But when running the app with the emulator, it doesn't work. Deeplinks are not detected and safari open the link.

Does anyone has a solution or a lead I could follow ?

Ionic 3
iOS platform v.4.5.4 .
@ionic-native/deeplinks v.4.5.3

Comment: hello. Did you manage to make this work ?

Comment: Hi, how you managed to resolve it as its working in android but not on IOS?